# Remove an element based on its ancestor presence in first child of its ancestor

Tags: xslt

Please suggest for how to remove an element(mstyle) based on its ancestor(msubsup) presence  in first child (position=1) of its(msubsup) ancestor(msub or msup).

See my comments placed in XML as well as in XSLT for quick reference. (XSLT2)

Input XML:

```
<root>
<math>

<msubsup>
    <mrow><mi>H</mi></mrow>
    <mstyle width="70%"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mstyle><!-- mstyle to retained because NO ancestor like 'msub' or 'msup' found for msubsup--> 
</msubsup>

<mrow><mtext>The text 1</mtext></mrow>

<msub>
    <mrow><!--First Child to msub-->
        <msubsup>
            <mi>K</mi>
            <mstyle width="70%"><mn>2</mn></mstyle><!--mstyle required to remove because   msubsup found in 'msub's first child area -->
            <mo>+</mo>
        </msubsup>
    </mrow>
    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow><!--second Child to msub-->
</msub>

<mrow><mtext>The text 2</mtext></mrow>

<msup>
    <mrow><!--First Child to msup-->
        <mrow>
            <msubsup>
                <mrow><mi>K</mi></mrow>
                <mstyle width="70%"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mstyle><!--mstyle required to remove because   msubsup found in 'msup's first child area -->
                <mrow><mo>+</mo></mrow>
            </msubsup>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow><!--second Child to msup-->
</msup>

<mrow><mtext>The text 3</mtext></mrow>

<msub>
    <mrow><mn>A</mn></mrow><!--First Child to msub-->
    <mrow><!--second Child to msub-->
        <mrow>
            <msubsup>
                <mrow><mi>K</mi></mrow>
                <mstyle width="70%"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mstyle><!--mstyle required to RETAIN because   msubsup found in 'msub's SECOND child area -->
                <mrow><mo>+</mo></mrow>
            </msubsup>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
</msub>

</math>

</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mstyle">

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::msubsup/ancestor::msub or ancestor::msubsup/ancestor::msup"><!--Checking for msubsup is having ancestor like msub or msup-->
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ancestor::msubsup/ancestor::*[position()=1]/ancestor::msub or ancestor::msubsup/ancestor::*[position()=1]/ancestor::msup"><!--Remove mstyle element, bcs its ancestor::msubsup found in FIRST child of MSUB or MSUP -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates/><!--Removing mstyle element only, not its descendants -->
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy><!--Retaining mstyle(ancestor::msubsup), because found at second child of musb or msup -->
                    </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

```
<root>
<math>
<msubsup>
    <mrow><mi>H</mi></mrow>
    <mstyle width="70%"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mstyle><!-- mstyle to retained because NO ancestor like 'msub' or 'msup' found for msubsup--> 
</msubsup>
<mrow><mtext>The text 1</mtext></mrow>

<msub>
    <mrow>
        <msubsup>
            <mi>K</mi>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mo>+</mo>
        </msubsup>
    </mrow>
    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
</msub>
<mrow><mtext>The text 2</mtext></mrow>

<msup>
    <mrow>
        <mrow>
            <msubsup>
                <mrow><mi>K</mi></mrow>
                <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
                <mrow><mo>+</mo></mrow>
            </msubsup>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
</msup>
<mrow><mtext>The text 3</mtext></mrow>

<msub>
    <mrow><mn>A</mn></mrow>
    <mrow>
        <mrow>
            <msubsup>
                <mrow><mi>K</mi></mrow>
                <mstyle width="70%"><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mstyle><!--Required retain mstyle here, bcs msubsup found in second child of msub or msup-->
                <mrow><mo>+</mo></mrow>
            </msubsup>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
</msub>

</math>


</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- The identity transform. -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match mstyle and output nothing if its msubsup parent is a descendent
         of the first child of msub or msup.-->
    <xsl:template match="msub/*[1]//msubsup/mstyle|msup/*[1]//msubsup/mstyle">
        <!-- Still want to output children of mstyle though. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Element mstyle should be removed, but inner elements to be retained, thanks for suggestion